# Three.js r74 JSONLoader binds duplicate of all geometry to first bone

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm rewriting this question since I understand more about the bug now. It looks like when using the JSONLoader in r74, the first named bone in an exported Maya scene gets a duplicate of all the geometry.

EDIT: Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evantron3000/1j5xwhbf/)

In this example I have 2 boxes. Each box is bound to a single bone, and each of those bones has keyframes that animate the position and rotation. There is another bone that has no geometry bound to it, and has keyframes that make no change to its position or rotation.

The stationary bone is called "joint1" in Maya. The bones that actually have geometry bound to them are called "joint2" and "joint3". If I were to rename the stationary bone "joint4" the result would be a duplicate of both boxes attached to the currently animating "joint2".

My guess is that either this is a bug, or I'm doing something wrong when loading the animations. Any tips would be appreciated. The only workaround I can figure out right now is to separate each animated object into a separate file, and that's really not feasible. Plus, that wouldn't solve the issue when I have a multi-bone skeleton. This example is just single bone rigs with no actual deformation.

Here's my current loader code.

```
        //Load Scene, Materials, and Animation

        var mixer, mesh;
        var actions = {};
        var sceneLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        sceneLoader.load( sceneFile, function( geometry,materials ) {
           materials.forEach( function( material ){
              material.skinning = true; 
           });

            mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) );

            mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( mesh );
            actions.main = mixer.clipAction( geometry.animations[ 0 ]);
            actions.main.setEffectiveWeight( 1 );
            actions.main.play();

            scene.add( mesh );

        });

        //Render

        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );

            controls.update;

            var delta = clock.getDelta();
            var theta = clock.getElapsedTime();

            if ( mixer ) { mixer.update( delta ); }

            renderer.render(scene, camera)
        }

        render();
```

Comment: Maybe good to add a fiddle with the not working example too?

Comment: I updated the question and included a JSFiddle of the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue, but I've found an ok workaround.

Since the duplicated geometry always gets assigned the default lambert shader that is always included when using the Maya Exporter. As long as all the objects that are intended to be kept have a material other than the default in Maya, you can insert

```
mesh.material.materials[0].visible = false;
```

into the loader code which will make any material with the default lambert invisible.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evantron3000/cjLr0tk5/)