# Skinned mesh exported from Maya is duplicated in Three.js scene

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, maya

When I export an animated skinned mesh from Maya using the Three.js exporter, it always appears to have a duplicate mesh combined with it that is not animated.

I've tried all the export settings I can think of and also made sure there is not another mesh being exported with it. I can reproduce the problem by skinning, animating, and exporting any mesh.

I compared my exported .js file and I can't see any difference between that file and this working three.js example:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_skinning_simple

Comment: looks like you exported the `intermediate object` with the skinned object.

Comment: It does look that way, but there is no intermediate object selected for export in Maya and only one mesh imported into the Three.js scene. I confirmed this using the three.js inspector.

Comment: It seems like this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614699/three-js-r74-jsonloader-binds-duplicate-of-all-geometry-to-first-bone
but I wasn't able to fix my problem following the suggestion of making the first material invisible. I only see a single mesh and material.

Answer (score 0):

This problem does not exist using a previous release of Three.js (r73).

There appears to be a bug in r74 and r75.